# Passing this as a parameter to an angularjs function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 team" ng-mouseover="showDetails()" >
           ....
           ....
           ....
</div>
```

I want to pass the whole section of where the mouse is over to an angularjs function so then I will find each child.

```
 $scope.showDetails = function(item){
        console.log(item);
        var element = $(item).find('#child1');
     }
```

I tried **showDetails(this)** and **showDetails($this)** and **showDetails({{this}})** but they dont seem to work. The first one print some stuff on the console but maybe something wrong since it cannot find the child1. What I am doing wrong?

```
a {$id: "004", this: a, $$listeners: Object, $$listenerCount: Object, $parent: a…}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `ngMouseover`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it through `$event.target`.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 team" ng-mouseover="showDetails($event)" >
    ....
</div>

$scope.showDetails = function(evt){
    console.log(evt.target);
    var element = $(evt.target).find('#child1');
}
```

This probably means you are wanting to manipulate elements in your controller, this is a no-no. You should make a custom directive with your desired functionality.

Comment: I do not suggest operate element in Controller, it can be move to directive, I think.